# How to error trap in Jenkins Execute shell?

Tags: git, shell, jenkins, error-handling

I am running a bunch of git operations in execute shell Jenkins configurations.  I do see the error being generated, but Jenkins job still shows up as successful.  How do I trap the error below  so it fails the status of Jenkins job:

**error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@git**

After editing jenkins shell git push to look like this:

**git push "$target" --all | grep -z "error:" && exit 1**

Jenkins job is still marked successful even though the error is occuring

```
15:24:06  ! [remote rejected] test/test/testBranch ->test/test/testBranch (pre-receive hook declined)
15:24:06 error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@git.testing-repo/test/test-test.git'
15:24:06 hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
15:24:06 hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
15:24:06 hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
15:24:06 hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
15:24:06 hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
15:24:06 Everything up-to-date
15:24:07 Finished: SUCCESS
```

EDIT #2 All the changes exist in Execute shell (#!/bin/bash) configuration part of jenkins.

Script:

```
RESPONSE=$(git push "$target" --all | grep "error:" || true)


    if [ -n "$RESPONSE" ]; then
        exit 1
    fi
```

Output:

```
14:42:30 Cloning into bare repository 'testing-repo.git'...
14:44:25 From bitbucket.org:TEST/testing-repo
14:44:25  * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
14:44:29 remote:
14:44:29  ! [remote rejected] test/test/testBranch ->test/test/testBranch (pre-receive hook declined)
14:44:29 error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@git.testing-repo/test/test-test.git'
14:44:29 hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
14:44:29 hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
14:44:29 hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
14:44:29 hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
14:44:29 hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
14:44:29 Everything up-to-date
14:44:29 Finished: SUCCESS
```

EDIT #3: Actually when I am debugging in the shell $RESPONSE doesn't contain any data, so it would explain why it doesn't change the status of the jenkins job.  So it seems even if git command actually did what it is supposed to, it did not feed output of the command into $RESPONSE

EDIT #4 RESPONSE=$(git push "$target" --all 2>&1 | grep "error:" || true) did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is strange because this `git push` failed so it should return an exit code different from `0` which then should fail your build. The exit code of last command of the Jenkin's Execute Shell build step is what determines the success/failure of the Build Step. `0` - success, anything else - failure. If you can provide more data maybe I could debug this. What exit code is being returned after your git push? (You can check exit code of last command by typing: `echo $?`) Can you also add some example?

But don't worry I also have a simple workaround for you (Maybe not pretty but it works). You can always manually say to Jenkins to fail build by setting error code by yourself. In this case, you can `grep` your git push for error. If there is, exit with code 1.

```
git push ... | grep -z "error: failed to push some refs to" && exit 1 || true
```

Or more generic:

```
 git push ... | grep -z "error:" && exit 1 || true
```

#### Edit

Where do you exactly run this `git push` command? In execute shell build step? Do you use [Jenkins Source Code Management](http://www.mastertheboss.com/cool-stuff/jenkins/jenkins-source-code-management-with-git)? (It will make easier to work with repositories inside Jenkins build)

Dummy job to show that `exit 1` will force failure:

[image: Build Execute shell]
[image: Console Output]

you can always try doing the same more bash script like:

```
RESPONSE=$(git push ... | grep -z "error:" || true)

if [ -n "$RESPONSE" ]; then
  exit 1
fi
```

also, I've added `|| true` to workaround commands because I have forgotten that `grep` will `exit 1` if no line is selected:

> Exit status is 0 if any line is selected, 1 otherwise

Which means that this would force fail all of your builds.

Comment: Thank you Raoslaw.  All I am trying to do is synchronizing 2 repos in jenkins shell between 2 instances of BitBucket.  Some of pushes are being rejected due to (pre-receive hook declined) and it generates final error above.  Unfortunately it doesn't fail Jenkins job.  I just want to have a warning when the push fails by marking Jenkins job failed or unstable.  Will try your suggestion.  Thanks again.

Comment: Modified my question with more information, error still doesn't mark status of Jenkins job as a failure.

Comment: @Dzerlig Okay let me check, I'll create dummy job to debug that. By the way, do you use Execute shell build step?

Comment: @Dzerlig Please look at the edit. Can you add you execute shell to question? Maybe there is something wrong or a typo. And if you want to make build unstable just set in Execute Shell Advanced option Exit code to set build unstable to 1.

Comment: thank you again!  It is still an issue and my suspicion its because output to git push is quite large, where "error:" is just a small part of the output, so I don't think $RESPONSE parses it correctly.  I will do another edit of the question.  To show my config and output

Comment: Thank you!  I got it, Edit #4 :)